# ERROR ITMS-90704: Missing App Icon. When trying to publish app to TestFlight

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native, release, testflight

ERROR ITMS-90704: Missing App Icon. An app icon measuring 1024 by 1024 pixels in PNG format must be included in the Asset Catalog of apps built for iOS, iPadOS, or watchOS. Without this icon, apps cannot be submitted for review. For details, see https://developer.apple.com/ios/human-interface-guidelines/icons-and-images/app-icon/.
Return status of iTunes Transporter was 1: ERROR ITMS-90704: Missing App Icon. An app icon measuring 1024 by 1024 pixels in PNG format must be included in the Asset Catalog of apps built for iOS, iPadOS, or watchOS. Without this icon, apps cannot be submitted for review. For details, see https://developer.apple.com/ios/human-interface-guidelines/icons-and-images/app-icon/.
The call to the iTMSTransporter completed with a non-zero exit status: 1. This indicates a failure.

**What i tried:**

1. Generate new icon multiple times form different websites
2. Remove alpha channel from icon
3. Rename icon to match other icons naming conventions, and then tried ITunesArtwork name, icon-1024, etc
4. Tried adding icon through Xcode and also tried adding manually to Contents.json
5. Checked icons actual size in folder
6. Checked icon path
7. Added our icons from other app which has no problem with this to this app and tried release pipeline again  which also failed